# Comments (#) go to start of line in the insert mode in Vim

Tags: python, vim, comments, indentation

Whenever I want to add a comment to an indented line in vim, I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> (open a new row above the current, switch to insert mode) and start typing a Python comment (using `#`). That hash is then magically moved to the start of the line (no indentation) and I have to click tab a few times.

Anyone know how to work around it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I suppose you have `set smartindent` in your .vimrc

See `:h smartindent`

```
When typing '#' as the first character in a new line, the indent for
that line is removed, the '#' is put in the first column.  The indent
is restored for the next line.  If you don't want this, use this
mapping: ":inoremap # X^H#", where ^H is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-H.
When using the ">>" command, lines starting with '#' are not shifted
right.
```

I believe you don't need smartindenting while coding python. So just remove it from your settings or add the following to your .vimrc:

```
au! FileType python setl nosmartindent
```

Comment: That answer is obviously right on the money, thanks a lot. I had missed this completely.

However, I wouldn't agree on the fact that I don't need the smartindenting since python is all about it. I can just add the exception, instead.

I wonder, though, which is the best, the manual's inoremap or the one provided by Haes? Or rather, what's the difference?

Comment: I think that for python `smartindent` is useless. Python programmer don't need an indent to be auto-inserted 1. after a line ending in '{'; 2. before a line starting with '}'. And keywords from `cinwords` are correctly processed by python filetype indentation.

Comment: Basicly inoremaps are the same. The only drawback this inoremap has --   you can't shift comments to the right with `>>`

Comment: Could you elaborate on that setting? What does it do exactly?

Comment: @Maxim Sincere thanks, this solved the rather annoying issue for me immediately, with no apparent drawbacks.

Comment: I still get the same annoying behaviour after `:set nosmartindent` and having that `au!...` line... Oh, I had `cindent` on.

Comment: I know this is old, but re: `smartindent` for Python, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18415867/1858225

Comment: No one should even have 'set smartindent' in their vimrc.  You're supposed to use 'filetype indent on'.

Answer (score 10):

try putting that in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead *.py inoremap # X<c-h>#
```

This will make that the insertion of the hash (pound) sign is always indented in Python source files.

Comment: Thanks @Haes, I actually would prefer to leave smartindent on while editing python files. Perhaps it's trivial to add a 'tab' after starting a new if statement, but it's what I'm used to.

Comment: Ok, actually what I needed was "filetype plugin indent on", then I disabled smartindent for python.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this because I was having the same issue in haskell when using cindent.

You can configure what prompts the reindenting by modifying the contents of cinkeys:

I added the following to my vimrc to stop `#` triggering the behaviour

```
"when you type a hash as the first character stop it triggering reindent
set cinkeys -=0#
```

Comment: I’m not sure using cindent when writing haskell makes any sense. Simpler to let the haskell indent script do its thing, and not enable cindent globally (if you have)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble what haskell indent thing are you using?  I think I tried one but it did terrible things!  cindent doesn't do a bad job but it's not perfect, I just have it enabled for the haskell file type

Comment: `filetype indent on` turns on indents per language.. i havent tried it with haskell, but i assume it works

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Nerd Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218), which is a plugin that allows you to add comments to lines in most languages automatically. You simply place the cursor at the line you are interested in and type <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and the line will be commented out. The same keystrokes will remove the comment to reveal the line.

So if you have:

```
def func():
  print("indented") <- cursor position in command mode
```

Type <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and you get:

```
def func():
  #print("indented")
```

Comment: comments.vim is a lightweight alternative http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1528