# autoindent is subset of smartindent in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

> **:help autoindent** : Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing 
>   in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command). ...
>
> **:help smartindent** : Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line.  Works for C-like
>    programs, but can also be used for other languages. ...
>
> **Normally 'autoindent' should also be on when using 'smartindent'.**
>   An indent is automatically inserted:
>
> - After a line ending in '{'.
> - After a line starting with a keyword from 'cinwords'.
> - Before a line starting with '}' (only with the "O" command).
>
>   When typing '}' as the first character in a new line, that line is
>        given the same indent as the matching '{'. ...

**smartindent** also coping indent from current line when starting a new line. That means **autoindent** feature is subset of **smartindent** feature and no need of **autoindent** if **smartindent** is on, right? Why **autoindent** should be turn on?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`smartindent` is an old script that was meant, when it was written, to be a "smart" complement to `autoindent`. Since then, most languages have either specific indentation functions or use `cindent` with specific options.

Generally, `smartindent` shouldn't be used at all.

The following lines are usually enough to deal with indentation:

```
set autoindent
filetype plugin indent on
```

`autoindent` is not strictly necessary but it's good to have it when working with plaintext.